# why do I get invalid syntax in mypy with await expression?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mypy

```
# file test.py
import asyncio
from inspect import iscoroutine
from typing import Any


async def a():
    print('run a')
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 1


async def b():
    # type: () -> Any
    print('run b')
    return a()


async def g():
    # type: () -> Any
    print('run g')
    s = b()
    while iscoroutine(s):
        print('in g', s)
        s = await s
    return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    a = loop.run_until_complete(g())
    print('finish ', a)
```

when running above code using python3.6.6, I got:

```
run g
in g <coroutine object b at 0x10a980938>
run b
in g <coroutine object a at 0x10a95d620>
run a
finish  1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems everything's fine. but when running `mypy test.py`, I got `test.py:24: error: invalid syntax`. What does it mean?
Is there something wrong in my code?
My python interpreter version is 3.6.6, mypy version is 0.620.

Answer (score 2):

Huh, this is very weird!

I think this is a bug in [`typed_ast`](https://github.com/python/typed_ast), the library mypy uses to convert Python source code into an abstract syntax tree.

I was able to simplify your issue down to just the following:

```
import asyncio

async def g():
    # type: () -> None
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

This also gets a syntax error on the line containing the 'await'.

However, the error message goes away if you do this:

```
import asyncio

async def g() -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

This same workaround (using the type hint syntax instead of the comment syntax also fixes the issue with your original program). It seems that for some reason, the comment-based type signature syntax and the 'await' keyword don't interact well.

I suspect the reason why this issue wasn't uncovered earlier was because most people who are using async/await are also using Python 3's built-in annotation syntax -- the type comment syntax is mostly used when you want compatibility with Python 2, but async/await is Python 3 only...

Anyways, I would recommend filing an issue on either mypy's or typed_ast's issue tracker -- the mypy team monitors and maintains both repos. (Or, if you're up for it and have some spare time, maybe even try fixing the issue in `typed_ast` yourself? This feels more like an oversight then a fundamentally tricky bug to me.)

Comment: You are right! I use comment syntax because I type ```if False: import typing```  in my code. Seems  this also avoid syntax error: `async def g() -> 'None':`. maybe this is a good way to solve the issue.